# Should necroposting be allowed?

Tags: discussion

I've seen someone posting in a 2 years old question. [Link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48228/why-do-breathtaking-views-turn-into-boring-photos-and-how-can-i-do-better)

Should this be discouraged? The question already has an answer marked as useful by the OP. If people decides to just post a new question in year-old questions like this won't it clog up the active section of the home page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think it should be discouraged.  A certain amount of churn is good so people can see older questions and we even have badges for working on old questions.

It can be annoying if someone makes very minor edits on a ton of old questions at once, but adding good, new answers to old questions is a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually *encouraged* — see the [Necromancer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) and [Revival](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/revival) badges.

Of course, new answers should add new information, or otherwise add value with an improved explanation.

You worry that old questions will "clog up" the front page. But think of this site as a little more like Wikipedia than a web discussion forum. The goal is to build a repository of useful information. Old questions *should* be still valuable (or else possibly closed and removed).